# How do I stop my iPad's passcode buttons from lighting up?

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak

I have a jailbroken iPad 2 and I was wondering if it is possible to stop the passcode buttons from lighting up when they're pressed. Is there some sort of image somewhere that can be changed to keep this from happening?

Comment: I'm curious to know if you ever got this working. I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help. It's hard for me to get a hold of a JailBroken iPad.

Answer (score 2):

The image you're looking for is `/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/DeviceLockKeypadPressed~ipad.png`  Using iFile (or SSH), make a copy of `DeviceLockKeypad~ipad.png` into the same folder. Delete `DeviceLockKeypadPressed~ipad.png`, and rename your copied file to this. You could also edit the image to be a color other than blue.

Comment: I can't seem to find any image similar to that on the iPad.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running? The file should be called DeviceLockKeypadPressed~ipad.png (updated answer to reflect correct filename).

Comment: I'm running iOS 5.0.1. I tried searching for that file and it doesn't exist.

Comment: You should look directly for the file in iFile by going to / -> System -> Library -> CoreServices -> SpringBoard.app. If you still can't find it, give me a brief list (there should only be about six) of all the files that start with the letter "d" in that folder.

Comment: I said that I searched through the entire file system for that file. And none of those files in SpringBoard.app are it.

Comment: I'll borrow my friend's iPad2 and do a little more digging.

Comment: After looking on my friend's iPad2, I found the file. It's in the same location under the same name that I have previously stated. Here are a couple screenshots: http://ss.gy/o http://ss.gy/p

Comment: Obviously the keypad image exists. It's the pressed one that doesn't.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'll see what else I can find.